# Does anyone have an easy solution to parsing Exp-Golomb codes using C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, video, h.264

Trying to decode the SDP sprop-parameter-sets values for an H.264 video stream and have found to access some of the values will involve parsing of Exp-Golomb encoded data and my method contains the base64 decoded sprop-parameter-sets data in a byte array which I now bit walking but have come up to the first part of Exp-Golomb encoded data and looking for a suitable code extract to parse these values.

Comment: Where did you find out what is contained in sprop-parameter-sets?! I am searching the internets without a result... =| Can you give a link to documentation?! I'm interested in decoding a video size... thnx

Comment: Hey I found this: http://www.vcodex.com/files/h264_vlc.pdf

Comment: For the contents of the sprop-parameter-sets I had to refer to the following document ISO/IEC 14496-10:2005 which I'm afraid you have to pay for. Section 7.3.2.1.

Comment: The spec you require is available for free download from the ITU website here:-
http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264-200903-I/en

Select the freely downloadable PDF and you'll find the format detailed in section 7.3.2.1.1.

Sorry, wasn't being obtuse with my previous answer, just didn't know that the information was available in the public domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exp.-Golomb codes of what order ??
If it you need to parse H.264 bit stream (I mean transport layer) you can write a simple functions to make an access to scecified bits in the endless bit stream. Bits indexing from left to right.

```
inline u_dword get_bit(const u_byte * const base, u_dword offset)
{
    return ((*(base + (offset >> 0x3))) >> (0x7 - (offset & 0x7))) & 0x1;
}
```

This function implement decoding of exp-Golomb codes of zero range (used in H.264).

```
u_dword DecodeUGolomb(const u_byte * const base, u_dword * const offset)
{
    u_dword zeros = 0;

    // calculate zero bits. Will be optimized.
    while (0 == get_bit(base, (*offset)++)) zeros++;

    // insert first 1 bit
    u_dword info = 1 << zeros;

    for (s_dword i = zeros - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        info |= get_bit(base, (*offset)++) << i;
    }

    return (info - 1);
```

}

u_dword means unsigned 4 bytes integer.
u_byte means unsigned 1 byte integer.

Note that first byte of each NAL Unit is a specified structure with forbidden bit, NAL reference, and NAL type.

Comment: It's called "order", not "range"

Comment: Maybe, It was few years ago. Sorry!

Comment: I recognize this post is old, but I just want to say that this is the most elegant implementation of ExpGolomb decode that I have ever seen! I salute you t0k3n1z3r !!!

Comment: I'm glad that it was usefull)

Comment: Bug: remove the bare (*offset)++ after "u_dword info ...".  Otherwise it eats too many bits and throws off all following decodes.

Answer (score 5):

Accepted answer is not a correct implementation. It is giving wrong output. Correct implementation as per pseudo code from

> "Sec 9.1 Parsing process for Exp-Golomb codes" spec T-REC-H.264-201304

```
int32_t getBitByPos(unsigned char *buffer, int32_t pos) {
    return (buffer[pos/8] >> (8 - pos%8) & 0x01);
}


uint32_t decodeGolomb(unsigned char *byteStream, uint32_t *index) {
    uint32_t leadingZeroBits = -1;
    uint32_t codeNum = 0;
    uint32_t pos = *index;

    if (byteStream == NULL || pos == 0 ) {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (int32_t b = 0; !b; leadingZeroBits++)
        b = getBitByPos(byteStream, pos++);

    for (int32_t b = leadingZeroBits; b > 0; b--)
        codeNum = codeNum | (getBitByPos(byteStream, pos++) << (b - 1));

    *index = pos;
    return ((1 << leadingZeroBits) - 1 + codeNum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a c++ jpeg-ls compression library that uses golomb codes. I don't know if Exp-Golomb codes is exactly the same. The library is open source can be found at http://charls.codeplex.com. I use a lookup table to decode golomb codes <= 8 bits in length. Let me know if you have problems finding your way around.

Answer (score 1):

Revised with a function to get N bits from the stream; works parsing H.264 NALs

```
inline uint32_t get_bit(const uint8_t * const base, uint32_t offset)
{
    return ((*(base + (offset >> 0x3))) >> (0x7 - (offset & 0x7))) & 0x1;
}

inline uint32_t get_bits(const uint8_t * const base, uint32_t * const offset, uint8_t bits)
{
    uint32_t value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bits; i++)
    {
      value = (value << 1) | (get_bit(base, (*offset)++) ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return value;
}

// This function implement decoding of exp-Golomb codes of zero range (used in H.264).

uint32_t DecodeUGolomb(const uint8_t * const base, uint32_t * const offset)
{
    uint32_t zeros = 0;

    // calculate zero bits. Will be optimized.
    while (0 == get_bit(base, (*offset)++)) zeros++;

    // insert first 1 bit
    uint32_t info = 1 << zeros;

    for (int32_t i = zeros - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        info |= get_bit(base, (*offset)++) << i;
    }

    return (info - 1);
}
```