Investigating the accuracy of log2_max_frame_num_minus4 in H.264 SPS Decoding
I'm decoding H.264 Sequence Parameter Set (SPS) data, focusing on the log2_max_frame_num_minus4 parameter. I think this parameter is important because it defines MaxFrameNum, the maximum frame count used for frame indexing. According to the formula 
max_frame_num = 2^(log2_max_frame_num_minus4 + 4)
, MaxFrameNum should ideally be the smallest power of two that covers the total number of frames in the video. However, documentation doesn't explicitly confirm that this minimal coverage rule always applies, so I'm guessing and it's unclear if I should rely on it universally.
First, I tested several videos from several recorders. While some calculated values for MaxFrameNum are correct, others are either slightly off by a power of two (e.g., 512 instead of 1024) or completely incorrect (e.g., 8192 instead of 16).
I have also examined the bits at the relevant positions. Adjusting the position sometimes brings the result closer to the expected value depending on the video, but other times it distorts it even further.
Then I tested two OBS-generated videos one by one. Video 1 had 700 frames, so I expected MaxFrameNum = 1024. Video 2 had 461 frames, so I expected MaxFrameNum = 512. I set breakpoints at the input and output of my DecodeExpGolomb function. The first six bytes of the SPS (the relevant bytes so far) were identical in both videos. Consequently, the calls to DecodeExpGolomb before setting MaxFrameNum resulted in the same bit position. Logically, the value is wrong one time and not the other!
I would like to know if I can rely on this value and if some encoders do not set the MaxFrameNum value correctly.
If you wish, I can produce a "minimal" code example.
Edit. I created a new WinForms application to provide the necessary code—keeping it as minimal as possible, but still relevant.
Sequence Parameter Set
Edit 2: I am using the SPS that I've read from the AVC box (DecoderConfigurationRecord), not the SPS from a NALU.
Edit 3: I've written my own answer with code fixes and a summary for future readers 
Friend NotInheritable Class SequenceParameterSet
    Friend ReadOnly Property SequenceParameterSetLength As UInt16
    Friend ReadOnly Property SequenceParameterSetNALUnit As Byte()

    Friend Sub New(sequenceParameterSetLength As UInt16, sequenceParameterSetNALUnit As Byte())
        Me.SequenceParameterSetLength = sequenceParameterSetLength
        Me.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit = sequenceParameterSetNALUnit
    End Sub
End Class

My bitstream class
Friend NotInheritable Class BitStream
    Friend Property BytePos As Integer
        Get
            Return _BytePos
        End Get
        Private Set
            _BytePos = Value
            UpdateAbsBitPos()
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Property BitPos As Integer
        Get
            Return _BitPos
        End Get
        Private Set
            _BitPos = Value
            UpdateAbsBitPos()
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' as index 0–7
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Friend Property AbsBitPos As Integer
        Get
            Return _AbsBitPos
        End Get
        Private Set
            _AbsBitPos = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly _paddingLength As Integer
    Private _BytePos As Integer = 0
    Private _BitPos As Integer = 0
    Private _AbsBitPos As Integer

    Friend Sub New(paddingLength As Integer)
        Me._paddingLength = paddingLength
        UpdateAbsBitPos()
    End Sub

    Friend Sub SetInitialPositions(byteNumber As Integer, bitNumber As Integer)
        Me.BytePos = byteNumber
        Me.BitPos = bitNumber
    End Sub

    Friend Sub SetBitPosition(bitPosition As Integer)
        Me.BytePos = bitPosition \ 8
        Me.BitPos = bitPosition Mod 8
    End Sub

    Friend Sub IncrementBytePosition(byteNumber As Integer)
        Dim totalBits As Integer = (Me.BytePos + byteNumber) * 8 + Me.BitPos
        SetBitPosition(totalBits)
    End Sub

    Friend Sub IncrementBitPosition(bitNumber As Integer)
        Dim totalBits As Integer = (Me.BytePos * 8) + Me.BitPos + bitNumber
        SetBitPosition(totalBits)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"Byte: {Me.BytePos.ToString(New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")).PadLeft(_paddingLength, " "c)}, Bit: {Me.BitPos}, Absolute BitPos: {Me.AbsBitPos}"
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Updates the current bit position to a new absolute bit position.
    ''' Automatically adjusts the byte position as necessary.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="newBitPos"></param>
    Friend Sub UpdateBitPosition(newBitPos As Integer)
        SetBitPosition(newBitPos)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Updates the absolute bit position based on the current byte and bit positions.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub UpdateAbsBitPos()
        Me.AbsBitPos = (Me.BytePos * 8) + Me.BitPos
    End Sub
End Class

My byte tool class
Friend NotInheritable Class ByteTools
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Retrieves a single bit (0 or 1) from a given byte at a specified position.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="value"></param>
    ''' <param name="index"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Friend Shared Function GetBit(value As Byte, index As Integer) As Byte
        'https://stackoverflow.com/a/79055615/13936657
        If index < 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException($"{NameOf(index)} cannot be less than 0.", NameOf(index))
        ElseIf index >= 8 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException($"{NameOf(index)} cannot be greater than or equal to 8.", NameOf(index))
        End If

        index = index Mod 8
        Return CByte((value >> (7 - index)) And 1)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function ReadBitsWithinOneByte(value As Byte, startPositionIndexFrom As Integer, numBitsToRead As Integer) As Byte
        Return value << startPositionIndexFrom >> (8 - numBitsToRead) << (8 - numBitsToRead - startPositionIndexFrom)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function DecodeExpGolomb(byteStream As Byte(), ByRef nextPos As UInteger) As UInt32
        'https://stackoverflow.com/a/39841215/13936657
        If byteStream Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("The byte array must not be null.", NameOf(byteStream))
        End If
        If nextPos = 0UI Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Index must not be 0.", NameOf(nextPos))
        End If

        Dim leadingZeroBits As UInteger = UInt32.MaxValue

        Dim pos As UInteger = nextPos

        Dim b As Integer = 0
        While b = 0

            b = GetBitByPosArray(byteStream, CInt(pos))
            pos += 1UI
            If leadingZeroBits < UInt32.MaxValue Then ' In the original C++ code, leadingZeroBits is an uint32 (as here) but is initialized with -1 (so, UInt32.MaxValue), and overflows without exception.
                leadingZeroBits += 1UI
            Else
                leadingZeroBits = 0UI
            End If
        End While

        ' In the original C++ code, there was a for loop with bit-shifting on this line, but it was incorrect. In fact, that answer was intended to correct a previous one.

        nextPos = pos
        'Dim readBitsResult As UInteger = ReadBits(byteStream, CInt(pos) - 1, CInt(leadingZeroBits))
        Dim readBitsResult As UInteger = ReadBits(byteStream, CInt(pos), CInt(leadingZeroBits))
        nextPos += leadingZeroBits
        Dim extractedValue As UInteger = CUInt(Math.Pow(2, leadingZeroBits)) - 1UI + readBitsResult
        Return extractedValue
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function DecodeExpGolombSigned(byteStream() As Byte, ByRef nextPos As UInteger) As Integer
        If byteStream Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("The byte array must not be null.", NameOf(byteStream))
        End If
        If nextPos = 0UI Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Index must not be 0.", NameOf(nextPos))
        End If

        Dim leadingZeroBits As UInteger = UInt32.MaxValue

        Dim pos As UInteger = nextPos

        Dim b As Integer = 0
        While b = 0

            b = GetBitByPosArray(byteStream, CInt(pos))
            pos += 1UI
            If leadingZeroBits < UInt32.MaxValue Then ' In the original C++ code, leadingZeroBits is an uint32 (as here) but is initialized with -1 (so, UInt32.MaxValue), and overflows without exception.
                leadingZeroBits += 1UI
            Else
                leadingZeroBits = 0UI
            End If
        End While

        ' In the original C++ code, there was a for loop with bit-shifting on this line, but it was incorrect. In fact, that answer was intended to correct a previous one.

        nextPos = pos
        Dim tmpResult As Integer = CInt(ReadBits(byteStream, CInt(pos) - 1, CInt(leadingZeroBits)))
        Dim result As Integer
        If tmpResult > 0 Then
            result = (tmpResult + 1) >> 1
        Else
            result = -(tmpResult >> 1)
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function ReadBits(bytes As Byte(), bitStartPositionAsIndex As Integer, bitCount As Integer) As UInteger
        If bitCount = 0 Then Return 0UI

        If bytes Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("The byte array must not be null.", NameOf(bytes))
        End If
        If bitStartPositionAsIndex >= bytes.Length * 8 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException($"{NameOf(bitStartPositionAsIndex)} is too large ({bitStartPositionAsIndex}) for the byte array with a size of {bytes.Length} bytes.")
        End If
        If bitCount > 32 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("UInt32 can only hold up to 32 bits.")
        End If

        Dim startIndex As Integer = bitStartPositionAsIndex \ 8
        Dim endIndex As Integer = (bitStartPositionAsIndex + bitCount - 1) \ 8
        Dim remE As Integer = (bitStartPositionAsIndex + bitCount) Mod 8
        Dim a As UInt32 = bytes.Skip(startIndex).Take(1 + endIndex - startIndex).Select(AddressOf Convert.ToUInt32).Aggregate(Function(x, y) x << 8 Or y)
        Return a >> ((8 - remE) Mod 8) And (1UI << bitCount) - 1UI
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetBitByPosArray(buffer As Byte(), pos As Integer) As Byte
        If buffer Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("The byte array must not be null.", NameOf(buffer))
        End If

        pos = pos Mod (buffer.Length * 8)
        Return CByte((buffer(pos \ 8) >> (7 - pos Mod 8)) And 1)
    End Function
End Class

Reading SPS
Friend Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Some things here, e.g. NALU header
        '...

        Dim spsList As New List(Of SequenceParameterSet)()
        'Dim spsTest1 As New SequenceParameterSet(29US, New Byte() {103, 100, 0, 31, 172, 83})
        Dim spsTest2 As New SequenceParameterSet(30US, New Byte() {103, 100, 0, 42, 172, 217})
        spsList.Add(spsTest2)
        ReadSps(spsList)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The SPS contains a special profile (HDR, etc) und thus more fields.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="id"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Private Shared Function IsSpecialProfile(id As UInt32) As Boolean
        Dim ids As New List(Of UInt32) From {100, 110, 122, 244, 44, 83, 86, 118, 128, 138, 139, 134, 135}
        Return ids.Contains(id)
    End Function

    Private Sub ScalingList(ByRef scalingList As Integer(), sizeOfScalingList As Integer, ByRef useDefaultScalingMatrixFlag As Boolean, byteStream As Byte(), ByRef nextPos As UInteger)
        Dim lastScale As Integer = 8
        Dim nextScale As Integer = 8
        Dim delta_scale As Integer

        For j As Integer = 0 To sizeOfScalingList - 1
            If nextScale <> 0 Then
                delta_scale = ByteTools.DecodeExpGolombSigned(byteStream, nextPos)
                nextScale = (lastScale + delta_scale + 256) Mod 256
                useDefaultScalingMatrixFlag = (j = 0 AndAlso nextScale = 0)
            End If

            scalingList(j) = If(nextScale = 0, lastScale, nextScale)
            lastScale = scalingList(j)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadSps(spsList As List(Of SequenceParameterSet))

        Dim bs As New BitStream(7)

        ' ===================
        ' Start of SPS data
        ' ===================
        If spsList.Count > 0 Then ' SPS from DecoderConfigurationRecord → SPS-Liste
            Dim sps As SequenceParameterSet = spsList.First()
            Dim profile_idc As Byte = sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(1)
            Dim constraint_set0_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(2), 0)
            Dim constraint_set1_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(2), 1)
            Dim constraint_set2_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(2), 2)
            Dim constraint_set3_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(2), 3)
            Dim constraint_set4_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(2), 4)
            Dim constraint_set5_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(2), 5)
            Dim reserved_zero_2bits As Byte = ByteTools.ReadBitsWithinOneByte(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(2), 6, 2)
#If DEBUG Then
            If reserved_zero_2bits <> CByte(0) Then
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{NameOf(reserved_zero_2bits)}: {reserved_zero_2bits}. Supposed to be 0, but has to be ignored anyway.")
            End If
#End If
            Dim level_idc As Byte = sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(3)

            bs.SetInitialPositions(4, 0) '5. Byte
            Dim absoluteBitPos As UInteger = CUInt(bs.AbsBitPos)

            '0–31
            Dim seq_Parameter_set_id As UInt32 = ByteTools.DecodeExpGolomb(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit, absoluteBitPos)
            bs.UpdateBitPosition(CInt(absoluteBitPos))
#If DEBUG Then
            If seq_Parameter_set_id > 31UI Then
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{NameOf(seq_Parameter_set_id)}: {seq_Parameter_set_id}")
            End If
#End If

            If IsSpecialProfile(profile_idc) Then

                '0–3
                Dim chroma_format_idc As UInt32 = ByteTools.DecodeExpGolomb(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit, absoluteBitPos)
                bs.UpdateBitPosition(CInt(absoluteBitPos))
#If DEBUG Then
                If chroma_format_idc > 3UI Then
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{NameOf(chroma_format_idc)}: {chroma_format_idc}")
                End If
#End If

                Dim separate_colour_plane_flag As Integer
                If chroma_format_idc = CByte(3) Then
                    separate_colour_plane_flag = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(bs.BytePos), bs.BitPos)
                    bs.IncrementBitPosition(1)
                End If

                '0–6
                Dim bit_depth_luma_minus8 As UInt32 = ByteTools.DecodeExpGolomb(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit, absoluteBitPos)
                bs.UpdateBitPosition(CInt(absoluteBitPos))
#If DEBUG Then
                If bit_depth_luma_minus8 > 6UI Then
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{NameOf(bit_depth_luma_minus8)}: {bit_depth_luma_minus8}")
                End If
#End If

                ' Bit depth 0–6
                Dim bit_depth_chroma_minus8 As UInt32 = ByteTools.DecodeExpGolomb(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit, absoluteBitPos)
                bs.UpdateBitPosition(CInt(absoluteBitPos))
#If DEBUG Then
                If bit_depth_chroma_minus8 > 6 Then
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{NameOf(bit_depth_chroma_minus8)}: {bit_depth_chroma_minus8 }")
                End If
#End If
                ' mostly 0
                Dim qpprime_y_zero_transform_bypass_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(bs.BytePos), bs.BitPos)
                bs.IncrementBitPosition(1)
#If DEBUG Then
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{NameOf(qpprime_y_zero_transform_bypass_flag)}: {qpprime_y_zero_transform_bypass_flag }")
#End If

                Dim seq_scaling_matrix_present_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(bs.BytePos), bs.BitPos)
                bs.IncrementBitPosition(1)
                Dim Flat_4x4_16 As Integer() = Enumerable.Repeat(16, 16).ToArray() ' 4×4 Matrix, every value is 16
                Dim Flat_8x8_16 As Integer() = Enumerable.Repeat(16, 64).ToArray() ' 8×8 Matrix, every value is 16
                Dim limit As Integer = If(chroma_format_idc <> 3, 8, 12)
                Dim ScalingList4x4 As Integer() = New Integer(15) {}
                Dim ScalingList8x8 As Integer() = New Integer(63) {}
                Dim UseDefaultScalingMatrix4x4Flag As Boolean = False
                Dim UseDefaultScalingMatrix8x8Flag As Boolean = False
                If seq_scaling_matrix_present_flag = 1 Then
                    Dim seq_scaling_list_present_flag As Boolean() = New Boolean(limit - 1) {}
                    For i As Integer = 0 To limit - 1
                        seq_scaling_list_present_flag(i) = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(bs.BytePos), bs.BitPos) = 1
                        bs.IncrementBitPosition(1)
                        If seq_scaling_list_present_flag(i) Then
                            absoluteBitPos = CUInt(bs.AbsBitPos)
                            If i < 6 Then
                                ' If seq_scaling_list_present_flag(i) is set, use ScalingList4x4
                                ScalingList(ScalingList4x4, 16, UseDefaultScalingMatrix4x4Flag, sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit, absoluteBitPos)
                            Else
                                ScalingList(ScalingList8x8, 64, UseDefaultScalingMatrix8x8Flag, sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit, absoluteBitPos)
                            End If
                            bs.UpdateBitPosition(CInt(absoluteBitPos))
                        Else
                            ' if seq_scaling_list_present_flag(i) is not set, use standard matrices
                            If i < 6 Then
                                ScalingList4x4(i) = Flat_4x4_16(i) ' Set the standard 4×4-Matrix for i = 0..5
                            Else
                                ScalingList8x8(i - 6) = Flat_8x8_16(i - 6) ' Set the standard 8×8-Matrix for i = 6..11
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                Else
                    ' If seq_scaling_matrix_present_flag = 0 , use only the standard matrices
                    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
                        ScalingList4x4(i) = Flat_4x4_16(i)
                    Next
                    For i As Integer = 6 To 11
                        ScalingList8x8(i - 6) = Flat_8x8_16(i - 6)
                    Next
                End If

            End If

            ' supposed to be 0–12
            Dim log2_max_frame_num_minus4 As UInt32 = ByteTools.DecodeExpGolomb(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit, absoluteBitPos)
            bs.UpdateBitPosition(CInt(absoluteBitPos))
#If DEBUG Then
            If log2_max_frame_num_minus4 > 12UI Then
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{NameOf(log2_max_frame_num_minus4)}: {String.Format("{0:n0}", log2_max_frame_num_minus4)}")
            End If
#End If
            Dim maxFrameNum As UInt32 = CUInt(Math.Pow(2, log2_max_frame_num_minus4 + 4))
#If DEBUG Then
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{NameOf(maxFrameNum)}: {maxFrameNum}")
#End If

            ' 0–2
            Dim pic_order_cnt_type As UInt32 = ByteTools.DecodeExpGolomb(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit, absoluteBitPos)
            bs.UpdateBitPosition(CInt(absoluteBitPos))

            'ElseIf currentNalu.Type = CByte(7) Then ' SPS from Nalu

        End If
    End Sub
End Class


Do you have access to the H.264 specification?

Also, please post your current code.

@Dai Yes, I have. I've also edited my question.

@Daniel What bit position are you getting for reading log2_max_frame_num_minus4? And this position is talking about the SPS of {103, 100, 0, 42, 172, 217}?

@VC.One The absolute bit position is 38, which is in the 5th byte (byte index 4) and corresponds to the value 172 when the DecodeExpGolomb function is called. This function then reads the last two zeros of the 172 and the first bit of the 217. ReadBits then reads another 2 bits. The position is 43 afterward, meaning 5 bits were read in total.
And yes, those are exactly the data in question.

@Daniel Thanks for the update. The DecoderConfigurationRecord part makes sense now. Is this a found-on-net MP4 file? The SPS in an MP4 should not start with a byte 67 (decimal 103) since that is a NALU header. I will investigate the new details (bit positions) when I get a chance later on (just flying through SO site for now).. PS: "Video 1 had 700 frames, so I expected MaxFrameNum = 1024" Don't expect MaxFrameNum to be for "total frames in the whole video". It is more related to the GOP and the FrameNum and PicNum vars of some current GOP being processed by the H264 decoder.

@Daniel PPS: You say "The SPS contains a special profile" What s the profile's number and what part (chapter) of the specs has it listed? A profile_idc = 103 just doesn't make sense (especially in NALU bytes structure, and is more confusing if existing within an MP4 structure). Please assume it is a NALU header that should not be inside an MP4's DecoderConfigurationRecord, so then parse SPS starting from value 100 onwards. What happens if you run your function again but with first SPS byte removed, do you get a log2_max_frame_num_minus4 of 1? If yes then your code is fine.

This example is not actually from the internet but was saved using the VSDC Editor. However, most other videos (including internet-based ones) also have this combination of bytes.
Don't expect MaxFrameNum to be for 'total frames in the whole video.' It is more related to the GOP.  Ah, I already suspected that. That was also the main point of my question, even though I still had errors in the code.

profile_idc has the value 100. The if condition is found in Chapter 7.3.2.1.1 Sequence parameter set data syntax. I assumed it must be a ‘special’ profile because the if involves specific numbers, and only then are chroma_format_idc and other variables populated.
log2_max_frame_num_minus4 now also evaluates to 1 for me. Thank you for the table in your answer!

Your function ReadSps is not accounting for the NAL Unit header.
I suspect this is why you are getting some confusing numbers.
It's likely in the H264 Specs you are looking at: seq_parameter_set_data but you're not considering the Spec's other detail: nal_unit structure
Consider:
SPS NAL Unit = { [NALU header (is one byte, 0x67)] + [ RBSP data (is Profile IDC, etc) ] }

Therefore your code must read +8 bits ahead of expected position (is jumping the 8 bits by NALU header) to reach the right offset for some expected  bit's value extraction.
Alternatively, just parse the header in that same function. Hopefully the rest of code will now land on the correct offsets for the expected bits.
Solution:
I don't use VisualBasic but looking at your code, it could be written something like this:
Private Sub ReadSps(spsList As List(Of SequenceParameterSet))

    Dim bs As New BitStream(7)

    ' ===================
    ' Start of SPS data
    ' ===================
    If spsList.Count > 0 Then ' SPS from DecoderConfigurationRecord → SPS-Liste
        Dim sps As SequenceParameterSet = spsList.First()
        
        ' ### handle NALU Header (is type: SPS)
        Dim forbidden_zero_bit As Byte  = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(1), 0)
        Dim nal_ref_idc As Byte         = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(1), 1, 2)
        Dim nal_unit_type As Byte       = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(1), 3, 5)
        
        ' ### handle NALU RBSP (is SPS data)
        Dim profile_idc As Byte = sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(2)
        Dim constraint_set0_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(3), 0)
        Dim constraint_set1_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(3), 1)
        Dim constraint_set2_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(3), 2)
        Dim constraint_set3_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(3), 3)
        Dim constraint_set4_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(3), 4)
        Dim constraint_set5_flag As Byte = ByteTools.GetBit(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(3), 5)
        Dim reserved_zero_2bits As Byte = ByteTools.ReadBitsWithinOneByte(sps.SequenceParameterSetNALUnit(3), 6, 2)
#If DEBUG Then
        If reserved_zero_2bits <> CByte(0) Then
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{NameOf(reserved_zero_2bits)}: {reserved_zero_2bits}. Supposed to be 0, but has to be ignored anyway.")
        End If

Finally: To confirm your code results, the analysis is for SPS example:
int values: spsTest2 = { 103, 100, 0, 42, 172, 217 }
hex values: spsTest2 = { 0x67, 0x64, 0x00, 0x2A, 0xAC, 0xD9 }

Get your code to match the results shown in this guide:
Byte    BitPos      Sequence Parameter Set                          Binary  Value
==================================================================================
[0]     0           forbidden_zero_bit                                   0   = 0
[0]     1           nal_ref_idc                                         11   = 3
[0]     3           nal_unit_type                                    00111   = 7

[1]     8           profile_idc                                   01100100   = 100

[2]     16          constraint_set0_flag                                 0   = 0
[2]     17          constraint_set1_flag                                 0   = 0
[2]     18          constraint_set2_flag                                 0   = 0
[2]     19          constraint_set3_flag                                 0   = 0
[2]     20          constraint_set4_flag                                 0   = 0
[2]     21          constraint_set5_flag                                 0   = 0
[2]     22          reserved_zero_2bits                                 00   = 0

[3]     24          level_idc                                     00101010   = 42

[4]     32          seq_parameter_set_id                                 1   = 0
[4]     33          chroma_format_idc                                  010   = 1
[4]     36          bit_depth_luma_minus8                                1   = 0
[4]     37          bit_depth_chroma_minus8                              1   = 0
[4]     38          qpprime_y_zero_transform_bypass_flag                 0   = 0
[4]     39          seq_scaling_matrix_present_flag                      0   = 0

[5]     40          log2_max_frame_num_minus4                            1   = 0
[5]     41          pic_order_cnt_type                                   1   = 0
[5]     42          log2_max_pic_order_cnt_lsb_minus4                  011   = 2

.... not enough data to complete SPS Reading .... 

                    


With VC.One's table that includes the bit positions, I was able to identify two small bugs in my code.
First, I forgot to assign absoluteBitPos = CUInt(bs.AbsBitPos) before using log2_max_frame_num_minus4.
Second, there was an issue in my DecodeExpGolomb function. The while loop is supposed to count the leading zeros until it finds a 1. This 1 is then read by the ReadBits function. In cases where there were no leading zeros (as in my case, where the stream started directly with a 1), leadingZeroBits was passed to ReadBits with a value of 0. I've now added a fix to ensure that at least the 1 is read.
In DecodeExpGolomb:
..
..
..
nextPos = pos
Dim bitCount As Integer = Math.Max(1, CInt(leadingZeroBits)) ' Always read at least 1 bit
Dim readBitsResult As UInteger = ReadBits(byteStream, CInt(pos) - 1, bitCount) ' Starting from the position with the "1" where the while loop stops counting the leading zeros
If leadingZeroBits > 0UI Then
    nextPos += CUInt(bitCount)
End If
Dim extractedValue As UInteger = CUInt(Math.Pow(2, leadingZeroBits)) - 1UI + readBitsResult
Return extractedValue

Thanks to VC.One's help, I also now understand that max_frame_num is not necessarily accurate in every file. I've nevertheless asked a question and found a bug. So, we essentially had two stories in one.
